# Numbering rows of a select statement with union operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union, row-number

SQL SERVER: How can I enumerate the rows of a select statement with union operator, but without restarting the count, without duplicity and without subselect? Is it possible? I need something with performance. I got it with subselect and the function ROW_NUMBER(), but I need something faster. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Not clear. Can you provide test data and expected result.

Comment: How much time does the query take?  What's your definition of "fast enough"?  Have you examined the query plan and ensured it's not missing indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fastest that I can think of:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
from ((select * from A) union all
      (select * from B)
     ) t;
```

Two things.  First this uses `union all` rather than `union` -- so duplicates are not removed.  This speeds up the query if duplicate removal is not necessary.

Second, it uses `order by (select NULL))`.  In my experience, this seems to assign a sequential number on output without actually incurring the overhead of a sort.  This is strictly based on my experience.  I have not yet found SQL Server documentation that explains this.  But, I have used it in the past successfully.

Comment: WOW `order by (select NULL)` -- amazing.

Comment: GREAT! The 'select NULL' into ORDER BY works! The select almost returned immeditely. Before, It was taking about 4 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you could try this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);

SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (
        ORDER BY col1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        ) RN, col1, col2
FROM @T
```

Comment: why use count and not row_number?

Comment: I vote for "SUM(1) OVER ORDER BY col1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)"  :-)